# Looping to name variables

Tags: r

How can I achieve the same as the code bellow by using a loop through the list of team names in R?

```
teamnames <- list("Arsenal", "Bournemouth", "Brighton", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "CrystalPalace", "Everton", "Leicester", "Liverpool",
                  "ManCity", "ManUtd", "Newcastle", "Southampton", "Tottenham", "Watford", "Watford", "WestHam", "Wolves")


Arsenal_fixtures <- read.csv("Arsenal_fixtures.csv")
Bournemouth_fixtures <- read.csv("Bournmouth_fixtures.csv")
Brighton_fixtures <- read.csv("Brighton_fixtures.csv")
Burnley_fixtures <- read.csv("Burnley_fixtures.csv")
Chelsea_fixtures <- read.csv("Chelsea_fixtures.csv")
CrystalPalace_fixtures <- read.csv("CrystalPalace_fixtures.csv")
Everton_fixtures <- read.csv("Everton_fixtures.csv")
Leicester_fixtures <- read.csv("Leicester_fixtures.csv")
Liverpool_fixtures <- read.csv("Liverpool_fixtures.csv")
ManCity_fixtures <- read.csv("ManCity_fixtures.csv")
ManUtd_fixtures <- read.csv("ManUtd_fixtures.csv")
Newcastle_fixtures <- read.csv("Newcastle_fixtures.csv")
Southampton_fixtures <- read.csv("Southampton_fixtures.csv")
Tottenham_fixtures <- read.csv("Tottenham_fixtures.csv")
Watford_fixtures <- read.csv("Watford_fixtures.csv")
WestHam_fixtures <- read.csv("WestHam_fixtures.csv")
Wolves_fixtures <- read.csv("Wolves_fixtures.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `paste` to add the suffix `_fixtures.csv` in the 'teamnames' vector and read at once into a `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(paste0(teamnames, "_fixtures.csv"), read.csv)
```

and then set the names of the `list` elements for proper identification

```
names(lst1) <- paste0(teamnames, "_fixtures")
```

If we want to pull the elements of the `list`, use `[[`

```
lst1[["Arsenal_fixtures"]]
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
lst2 <- map(str_c(teamnames, "_fixtures.csv"), read_csv)
```